# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' When using dagger2 in project

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt, invocationtargetexception

`Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.40.5'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5'

}
```

getting this error while using dagger in my project dependency

clean project with  ./gradlew clean build and rebuild project done but not working,

Comment: There are usually more errors in the output, it'd be useful if you posted the actual stacktrace - based on the info you shared it's virtually impossible to troubleshoot the issue. You're also using a relatively old version of Dagger, you might try upgrading to the latest.